# Greyscale Effect on Mouse Hover with Transparent PNG Image

Tags: css, svg, grayscale

I was looking for grayscale effect on mouse hover on image and found this code which indeed worked. But I got another problem that I have PNG images with transparent background which is filled with white background on mouse hover using below code.
I do have alternative of using two different background images this seems much clean and short.
Could you pls suggest what modification should be done and what alternative can I have?

```
img.grayscale {
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg
 xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter
 id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333
 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/>/filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */   filter: gray;

  /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  /* Chrome 19+ & Safari
 6+ */
}
img.grayscale:hover {
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work because of syntax errors, you did not close the comments properly. Beside that, the filter should work as expected:

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

img.grayscale {
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */ 
  filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */ 
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
}

img.grayscale:hover {
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.lavera.de/fileadmin/_processed_/csm_Avocado-Frei_7fac93857c.png" alt="" class="grayscale">
```

Comment: Thanks Aziz but this code is already working. My problem is that I am using PNG images with transparent background which is filled with white background on mouse hover with the above code. How can I achieve transparent background of PNG image as is it on mouse hover?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, there is no white background on hover. What browser are you using? Do you see white background in my demo?

Comment: Thanks Aziz. Parent element of the image was showing background not the PNG image. My mistake!